# EIP712: ecrecover returns different address

Tags: solidity

I am trying to sign typed data via MetaMask "eth_signTypedData_v4". Recovering signer via recoverTypedSignature_v4 returns correct address that I signed my data with. But smart contract returns wrong address every time as ecrecover output. Can't understand what is wrong with the code.

js:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();// 签名
    const signerAddress = (await signer.getAddress()).toLowerCase();
    const originalMessage = {
        types: {
            EIP712Domain: [
                { name: "name", type: "string" },
                { name: "version", type: "string" },
                { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
                { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" }
            ],
            Greeting: [
                { name: 'contents', type: 'string' },
                { name: "sender", type: "address" },
                { name: "x", type: "uint256" }
            ],
        },
        primaryType: 'Greeting',
        domain: {
            name: 'SignatureVerifyTest',
            version: '1',
            chainId: 31337,
            verifyingContract: "0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3"
        },
        message: {
            contents: 'Hello',
            sender: signerAddress,
            x: 123
        }
    };
    const signedMessage = await signer.provider.send("eth_signTypedData_v4", [signerAddress, JSON.stringify(originalMessage)]);
    const { v, r, s } = ethers.utils.splitSignature(signedMessage);
    console.log('signerAddress:', signerAddress)
    console.log("r:", r);
    console.log("s:", s);
    console.log("v:", v);
```

```
        bytes32 eip712DomainHash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256("EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)"),
                keccak256(bytes("SignatureVerifyTest")),
                keccak256(bytes("1")),
                block.chainid,
                address(this)
            )
        );

        bytes32 hashStruct = keccak256(
            abi.encode(keccak256("Greeting(string contents,address sender,uint256 x)"), contents, sender, x)
        );


        bytes32 hash = ECDSA.toTypedDataHash(eip712DomainHash, hashStruct);
        address signer = ECDSA.recover(hash, v, r, s);

        console.log("sender", sender);
        console.log("signer", signer);
```

Comment: Stuck with the same issue, but using web3j (java). With web3js I'm able to make it work, you can check the openzeppelin workshop https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/workshops/blob/master/25-defender-metatx-api/src/signer.js

Answer (score 0):

Try following for the chainId

```
const network = await ethers.provider.getNetwork();
const chainId = network.chainId.toString();
```